# Multiplying 2 numbers without using * operator in Java

Tags: java, recursion, interview-questions

I saw this interview question and decided to solve using recursion in Java.

> Write a multiply function that multiples 2 integers without using *

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter first num: ");
    double num = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter second num: ");
    double numTwo = in.nextDouble();

    System.out.println(multiply(num, numTwo));
  }

  private static double multiply(double x, double y) {

    if (x == 0 || y == 0) {
      return 0;
    } else if (y > 0) {
      return x + multiply(x, y - 1);
    } else if (y < 0) {
      return -multiply(x, -y);
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
  }
}
```

What should I return instead of -1 to make this clear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### What should I return instead of -1 to make this clear?

Don't return -1, but recognise that you have exhausted the possible states of `y`, so simply do a `return` for the last possibility.

```
private static double multiply(double x, double y) {
    if (x == 0 || y == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (y > 0) {
        return x + multiply(x, y - 1);
    }
    return -multiply(x, -y);
}
```

Comment: Since `y` is a `double`, testing `y == 0`, `y > 0`, and `y < 0` doesn't exhaust the possible states. There's also `Double.isNaN(y)`.

Answer (score 4):

The challenge only requires you to work with integers. This technique would not actually be able to multiply two floating-point numbers, so don't use `double`. A proper solution for integers would not have a failure node that requires you to return -1.

A better algorithm to use would be the [Russian peasant method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_multiplication) which can be done by bitwise operations and addition.

Comment: What should I use to not to get "stackoverflow error" with huge numbers?

Comment: The Russian peasant method is much more efficient, and would not cause stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I fully agree with @200_success' answer. But I wouldn't remember the russian peasant method when asked this interview question. And I doubt they would give me enough time to look it up on the internet.

So let's look at your algorithm to solve it but try to reduce the recursion to a minimum.

The usual way to write a method like this is to first handle the special cases and quickly return, then handle the normal calculations.

I would write the method like this:

```
private static int multiply (int x, int y) {
    if(x == 0 || y == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    if(x < 0) {
        return -multiply(-x, y);
    }
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = x; i > 0; i--){
        result += y;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here I first handled the trival cases of multiply-by-zero. Then the special case where `x` is negative. I did use recursion here, because it makes handling the case really easy and only goes exactly 1 step deeper.

Then the actual algorithm literaly says: for x times, add y to the result.
I swapped the logic around compared to your solution because it's the [actual meaning](https://medium.com/i-math/why-5-x-3-5-5-5-was-marked-wrong-b34607a5b74c) of x * y.

Answer (score -1):

As these are integers, a naive solution to add one input over and over again in a for loop indexed from 0 to the other input - 1. You have to handle negatives as well.